# Github how to refer packages from multiple destinations in POM

Tags: github

I want to refer packages from Nexus as well as Github package registry in
https://github.com/org-name/repo1
(we have private organization implementation of github)

e.g
there is **repo1** and **repo2** in github

1. **repo1** is a springboot project and pom refers packages/libraries from **NEXUS**
2. **repo2** has published a jar package on Github package registry at below url - [NOT NEXUS]
   https://github.com/orgs/org-name/packages?repo_name=repo2

So where and how in below pom of **repo1** can I add the dependency for **repo2**
https://github.com/orgs/org-name/packages?repo_name=repo2

```
    <groupId>********</groupId>
    <artifactId>********</artifactId>
    <version>********</version>
    <name>********</name>
    <description>********</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!-- more here -->
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- some dependencies -->
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <!-- more here -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- few build plugins here -->
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <!-- few reporting plugins here -->
    </reporting>

    <!-- ORG specific Settings -->

    <distributionManagement>
        <!-- Publish the releases here -->
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>Releases</name>
            <url>https://repository.org-name.com:1234/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>

        <!-- Publish the snapshots here -->
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repository.org-name.com:1234/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repository.org-name.com:1234/nexus/content/repositories/central/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- moew nexus Settings -->
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>central</name>
            <url>https://repository.org-name.com:1234/nexus/content/repositories/central/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <!-- more plugin repositories -->
    </pluginRepositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>IntegrationTest</id>
            <build>
                <!-- few plugins here -->
            </build>
            
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

I tried to refer all libraries from Github instead of Nexus but still could not understand how to connect to private-org of github along with public org